# Generate php entities from orm.xml Doctrine

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony5, xmlmapper

Hi I'm on Symfony 5 and I'll like to generate php entities and update the scheme from a orm.xml file.

I think it worked before with doctrine:generate:entities command.

Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/tools.html#entity-generation), Doctrine itself still supports generating entities from a database.  If you really want to do this then you might give it a try.  You need to setup a couple of Doctrine config files and run vendor/bin/doctrine.  The link also explains some of the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The command `doctrine:generate:entities` was removed. The Doctrine ORM team does not encourage creating entities from existing schema and therefore deprecated that functionality in the ORM.

With the [MakerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) you can create entities, but as far as I know it won't create them from a schema, so you have to manually create each Entity, which admittedly can be annoying if you just want to generate them based on the existing schema anyway. Alternatively you can create a new "legacy" Symfony application (e.g. based on version 3.4 as this should still have the command), [create the entities from the schema as described in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), and then copy the generated entities over into your project. You will likely also have to run a search & replace for `AppBundle\Entity` -> `App\Entity`.

Comment: Thanks, thats look too hard for maintain the model. I cant understand why symfony deprecated it and didn't supply a new feature.

Comment: There are many reasons. Some, that cause the output to be incomplete, are stated in the docs: "Doctrine is able to convert approximately 70-80% of the necessary mapping information based on fields, indexes and foreign key constraints. Doctrine can’t discover inverse associations, inheritance types, entities with foreign keys as primary keys or semantical operations on associations such as cascade or lifecycle events."

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Was the question edited? Currently it asks how to generate php entities from **orm.xml.** What does "existing schema" to do with it?

Comment: Doctrine supports schema mappings in different formats. When using XML they are stored in files named after the entity, e.g. `User.orm.xml`. Similarly you could create matching PHP classes for the objects described in the xml files using a command. It would essentially create a `src/Entity/User.php` with all database fields as class properties and getters/setters for them. If you want to create a PHP class you should probably use the MakerBundle instead. Hope that helps